# Using ffmpeg to convert MXF fails

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I have an MXF video

I googled syntax to convert to mov and ran it in Mobaxterm on Win10.

```
"/drives/c/Program Files (x86)/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe" -i Clip0001.MXF -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ab 384k -sn -strict -2 output.mov
```

I view it in VideoLan and it looks great.

I load it into Magix Movie Studio 15 and audio is fine, but video is green!

ffmpeg output.mov....shows me:

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High 4:2:2) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4530 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
```

Even this does not work:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i Clip0001.MXF output.mov
```

Any suggestions on converting this?

Edit1:

Here is what it looks like in the editor:
[image]

Edit2:
Try this and it works, but quality is terrible.

```
ffmpeg.exe" -i Clip0001.MXF -c:v mpeg4 -c:a aac -ab 384k -sn -strict -2 output.mov
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFmpeg isn't failing; many video editors usually have limited-capability H264 decoders.

Your input has 4:2:2 chroma subsampling and ffmpeg will preserve that when it can. Here, it can and does. However, your video editor can only deal with 4:2:0 subsampled H264 streams.

So, use

`ffmpeg.exe -i Clip0001.MXF -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 384k -sn output.mov`

If this command throws an error for the AAC encoder due to the missing `-strict -2`, your ffmpeg is very old (> 3 years). You should upgrade.

Comment: Thank you.  it worked!  Here is my final: ffmpeg.exe -i Clip0001.MXF -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 384k -sn -preset veryfast -s 1920x1080 -b:v 5000k -crf 15 -framerate 24 output.mov

Comment: Can you give a brief synopsis on the 4:2:2 chroma subsampling?  And what in my post clued you into the problem?

Comment: .The parameters for output.mov has this: `yuv422p`.  Wiki has the details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling